# How can I tell Kubeflow's kfp command line interface about my self-signed cert?

Tags: ssl, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I am trying to run a pipeline on our Kubeflow cluster via our CI/CD pipeline using the kfp command-line interface.  However, when I call the `kfp run submit` command (with a host of options), I get the following error:

```
... connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)'))' ...
```

This is the tell-tale sign that it doesn't like my organization's self-signed cert.  I have a certificate authority .pem file that I would like to inform kfp of, but I don't see a way to do that in their documentation.

Does anyone know if I can?

Added detail:

- We use Tekton on the server
- These are the versions I'm using:

  - kfp: 1.8.21
  - kfp-tekton: 1.7.0
- Theoretically, [there is a kfp-tekton command line interface](https://github.com/kubeflow/kfp-tekton/blob/master/guides/kfp-user-guide/README.md#3-run-pipelines-using-the-kfp-tekton-bash-command-line-tool), which theoretically installs when I installed the `kfp-tekton` python package, but when I try to run it, I get:

```
$ kfp-tekton --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kfp_tekton.cli'
```

I don't think that is really supposed to work for my anyway because the documentation says:

> Please be aware that the kfp-tekton CLI only works for single user mode on kfp-tekton version 1.6+, for kfp-tekton 1.5 and below, please use the old kfp bash command.

Since our cluster us multi-tenant, I think that puts me back to using the `kfp` command.